# Putting a network interface up/down from command line

Tags: ubuntu, networking, command-line, wifi, network-interface

In Xubuntu 14.04, I tried to use both `ip` and `ifconfig` to handle a network interface, but they gave the same result.

```
$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
$ sudo ip link set wlan0 down
```

both correcly put down the interface and the connectivity does not work; but then

```
$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
$ sudo ip link set wlan up
```

did not restore the connectivity!

This is the output of `ip link show` after putting the interface down:

```
wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether <my_MAC_address> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.29/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

and this is the output after putting the interface up:

```
wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether <my_MAC_address> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.29/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

So it has no carrier and I can't access the web, but it has an IP!

1) Why? Shouldn't the `up` command restore the previous situation? I had to turn off and on the physical switch of the wireless board to browse again the web. I also tried with `dhclient -r wlan0` and `dhclient wlan0`, but the result was that neither the physical switch was useful and I had to restart the whole system.

2) Even after putting the interface down, the GUI connectivity icon was active and a connection to the wireless Access-Point was normally shown (even if no webpages were actually available). Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that `ifconfig` is not handling wireless stuff like ESSID, channel and key. Take a look to `iwconfig` instead.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man8/iwconfig.8.html

-EDIT-

You can also use "NetworkManager command line" `nmcli`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/461825/connect-to-wifi-from-command-line

Comment: thanks, but can you provide some example about deactivating and reactivating the wireless card? After reading the original manual (the one you provided is in Italian!) I did not find such an example.

Comment: If using *WPA* take also a look to `wpasupplicant`. A search to   "ubuntu WPA wifi command line" will give you many links like: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1798927 http://askubuntu.com/questions/461825/connect-to-wifi-from-command-line

Comment: with the second link I succeded to correctly shut down and then put up the interface. Maybe you can include it in your answer, and I will choose it.

Answer (score 2):

1) This answer is only for a wired connection.  Use ifup and ifdown, not ifconfig, unless you want to manually specify the parameters.  ifup will look at your network configuration in /etc/network/interfaces (or wherever your distro puts it).

2) If you're using wpa for your wifi, you cannot connect to it with just ifup; a helper application must be configured and running (usually wpa_supplicant).  Usually your distro will provide you with network scripts to perform these tasks automatically.

Comment: Ok, yes I use WPA very often. So a configuration is needed to be set up when the interface turns up again, which makes the re-connection a non-trivial task?